# Google Kubernetes Engine Time zone of Host

Tags: kubernetes, timezone, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using gcloud kubernetes engine. I was wondering if there was a way to automatically set up the time zone of nodes. (i'm using a autoscaler of nodes).

Thanks

Comment: General best practice is to 1) Always set the system time zone to UTC in server environments and 2) Don't *rely* on the system time zone in application code.  Applications should control their own time zone settings.  These bits of advice apply to *any* server environment, including Kubernetes.

Comment: This is currently not possible. Therefore, I would recommend that you open a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) to relay this query to our product engineers. This link will allow you to monitor the request progress and availability.